# Every polynomial bounded on [a,b] is of bounded variation.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, bounded-variation

**Question**: *Prove that every polynomial bounded on the compact interval [a,b] is of bounded variation*

My proof: Let $f(x)$ be a bounded polynomial of n degree. Then $f '(x)$ is also a polynomial bounded on [a,b] and also $f(x)$ is continuous on [a,b] since $f(x)$ is a polynomial. Thus $f$ is of bounded variation on [a,b].

I would appreciate if someone could point out any  mistakes in my proof or if more justifications are needed. Thanks

Comment: I think you are good, but you need more words/sentences. Why is it that if $f$ is bound then $f'$ is bound as well, and so on.

Comment: @DannyDan Thanks. Any tip as to how to prove that?

Comment: Assuming the polynomial is of a finite order. If it is bound then x between a and b then for any finite power x is also bound. and specifically $AiX^i$ (not good at the editing language) is also bound and hence the derived $i*Ai*X^(i-1)$ is also bound and so a finite sum of bound...