# How to show that $BV[0,1]$, the space of all functions on $[0,1]$ of bounded variation, is not complete under the supremum norm?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences, bounded-variation

How to show that $BV[0,1]$, the set of all functions of bounded variation, is not complete under the supremum norm? Can one explicitly construct a Cauchy sequence which does not converge or find a sequence in $BV[0,1]$ which converges in the sup-norm in $B[0,1]$ (the space of all bounded functions) but outside $BV[0,1]$?

Is there any other way of showing $(BV[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ is not complete?

Answer (score 2):

[Every polynomial has bounded variation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562475/every-polynomial-bounded-on-a-b-is-of-bounded-variation) Not every continuous function on $[0,1]$ has bounded variation. By the Weierstrass theorem, the closure of the space of polynomials under the supremum norm is the space of all continuous functions.

Comment: Uh huh , that is indeed a sophisticated solution . very nice +1) . Is there any explicit constructive argument ?

Comment: Could a proof be given using the characterization of B.V. functions as the difference of two  monotonic functions ? Ref. http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/variation.pdf